# Вертикальное выравнивание с помощью before, элемент не влазит?

Tags: html, css

Как и многие использую before для вертикального выравнивания. И вот если елемент по ширине не влазит, он выходит за род. блок. Что нужно делать в этом случае? Указывать ширину меньше чем у родителя? или использовать минусовой margin для псевдоелемента?

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/huham/1170/)

```css
.parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: grey;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.child {
  background: red;
  height: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.parent:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  min-height: inherit;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-left: -5px; //если раскоментировать появиться нужный блок
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <span class="child">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente laborum, veniam alias, dolore obcaecati at illo quis consectetur quod quisquam necessitatibus? Voluptatem distinctio odio, quia rerum iusto dolore quod rem!
     </span>
</div>
```

Comment: я ставлю `width: 98%`

Comment: Это во всех браузерах работает одинаково?

Comment: я не увидел проблемы , для чего в этом случае применять before ?http://jsfiddle.net/huham/1171/

Comment: @Geyan Вы имеете виду, что в этом случае можно использовать другой способ для выравнивания?
Но хотелось узнать можно ли в этом случае использовать минусовой марджин?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, топикстартер уже разобрался с данной проблемой, но, возможно, это решение пригодится кому-то еще.

Чтобы вертикально центрировать блок, используя псевдоэлемент `:before`, не обязательно задавать ему отрицательный `margin`, достаточно задать блоку-родителю `font-size:0px` - это избавит нас от "лишнего" пространства между `inline`-элементами:

```css
.parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: grey;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 0px;
}

.child {
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  height: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.parent:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <span class="child">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente laborum, veniam alias, dolore obcaecati at illo quis consectetur quod quisquam necessitatibus? Voluptatem distinctio odio, quia rerum iusto dolore quod rem!
     </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, за ответ. Я думаю, что вопрос решен.

Answer (score 1):

Для вертикального выравнивания уже можно использовать flex-box. Он уже достаточно широко поддерживается браузерами.

Свойство **margin** со значением **auto** применимое к **ребенку** flex-родителя - будет выравнивать как по горизонтали так и по вертикали

```css
#parent{
  display: flex; 
  height:300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#parent .child {
  width: 33.3%;
  height:30px;
  border:1px solid black;
  margin: auto; 
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child">ребенок</div>
   <div class="child">ребенок</div>
  <div class="child">ребенок</div>
</div>
```

Comment: а что мне делать с IE9? Для него отдельно задавать стили?